# $j$-invariant for a singular curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Say I have a plane cubic $f(x,y,z) \subset \mathbb{C}^3$ and I identify it with an elliptic curve by setting $z=1$ and end up with (perhaps after a change of variables) something of the form
\begin{equation}\label{e}
x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6=0.
\end{equation}
Is the $j$-invariant for this curve even defined?  A normal form is
\begin{equation}
y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6
\end{equation}
and the $j$-invariant is given by a simple formula in the coefficients.  But this formula assumes the curve is in normal form and in particular that the coefficient of the $y^2$ term is 1.  It seems to me that the first curve is not in normal form.

Comment: There are no $y$'s at all in your first equation. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes, and it's the source of my confusion.  That "curve" would just be the union of three lines, correct?  So if the $j$-invariant is defined at all I thought it would be some special value.

Comment: I guess I could be more concise in my original question: is the $j$-invariant defined only when the curve can be put in normal form? Or does this normal form just happen to lend itself to easy computation of the $j$-invariant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no good way to define a $j$-invariant for this cubic.

As you have recognized, this cubic consists of three lines, and is thus singular. Properly speaking, the $j$-invariant is only defined for smooth cubics.

However, the situation is worse than that. The homogenous cubic $xyz$ has zero locus in $\mathbb{P}^2$ consisting of three lines. Morally, though, there is a sense in which $xyz$ has $j$ invariant $\infty$. Namely, let $F_t(x,y,z)$ be a family of cubics, depending on a parameter $t$, such that $F_0=xyz$ and such that $F_t$ is smooth for $t$ near $0$ but nonzero. Then $\lim_{t \to 0} j(F_t)$ will be $\infty$. I don't see how to give a low-tech proof of this, but the high tech reason is that $xyz=0$ is a [semi-stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_curve) curve. The reason stable and semi-stable curves are so-named is because the behavior of invariants such as $j$ is continuous, or "stable", when they are perturbed.

By contrast, your curve consists of three lines *through a single point*; the technical term is that the lines are *concurrent*. In the $(x,y)$ coordinate chart, you have $3$ vertical lines, so they all pass through the point at vertical $\infty$. (In homogenous coordinates, the point $(0:1:0)$.) I claim that, for any number $j_0$, there is a family $F_t$ of cubics such that, for $t \neq 0$, the cubic $F_t$ is smooth with $j$-invariant $j_0$, and such that $F_0$ is your cubic.

**Proof:** First note that the symmetry group of $\mathbb{P}^2$ can take any three concurrent lines to any other three concurrent lines. So, I just need to build a family $F_t$ where $F_0$ is some triple of concurrent lines, and then apply a symmetry of $\mathbb{P}^2$ to that family.

Let $G$ be a cubic with $j$-invariant $j_0$. By making a change of coordinates if necessary, we can arrange that $G$ meets the line at $\infty$ in three distinct points. Then set $F_t(x,y,z) = G(x,y,tz)$. For $t \neq 0$, the cubic $F_t$ is isomorphic to $G$. When $t=0$, the cubic $F_t$ is the three lines joining the origin to the intersections of $G$ with the line at $\infty$. $\square$

Comment: Are you sure the curve $xyz = 0$ is semi stable? I thought the singularities of a semi stable curve should be ordinary. This means that there can only be two irreducible components going through a singular point, right? In your example there are 3 curves going through the singular point, no?

Comment: @Insti: I have converted your answer to a comment; answers should be reserved for posts that answer the question. But because you do not have 50 reputation points yet, [you can only comment on your own questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757). So, you didn't do anything wrong; the "add comment" button will only appear for you once you gain 50 points. By the way, here is an [explanation of reputation points](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238).

Comment: You are right that there should only be two components through any singularity. And there are! The components of $xyz=0$ are the lines $x=0$, $y=0$ and $z=0$. The form a triangle, with vertices at $(0:0:1)$, $(0:1:0)$ and $(1:0:0)$.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how the equations xyz =0 gives a triangle. it's just the three coordinate axes, right? For example....ow wait, are we talking projective here?

Comment: @Bana, yes, I am speaking projectively. I edited to try to make this more clear.